# Power requirements for hot tub (reading from label)

Tags: electrical, plumbing, hot-tub, project-planning

I am looking to purchase this hot tub from Craigslist and was trying to make sure I had enough power to feed it.

The label on it is really confusing. From my reading, it looks like it breaks down the amp requirements in terms of voltage and frequency. But the strangest thing is that the amps are lower for 120v than for 240v. There is also a breakdown of 3 wire vs 4 wire 240v installation (I assume to feed 120v components.) It's really strange. Have a look for yourself. The only thing I can come up with is that it states the power  draw for each mode and that I  will need 50a to run at full? I'm located in the US. Thanks

[image: Picture of label]

Comment: It looks to me like there are a lot of options you may have 120v pumps or larger 240 v pumps. If you have a 50a 240v 4 wire service to the tub you are golden this would be a very common size for a full sized tub with dual water pumps and a blower + heating. To know for sure we would need to know the size of the pumps & heater. Are there other options like ozonater or is it a salt water system that uses a platinum wire to create natural chlorine?

Comment: What make and model is it? Can you locate the manufacturers manual and installation instructions?

Comment: That spa has wiring OPTIONS.  You need more information, such as the installation manual as a first step.  It may also depend for example which heater and which motor are actually installed.

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me like it needs both 120V and 240V.

The 120 is likely for the water pump and controls while the 240 is for the water heater.

Here is a typical wiring diagram for a SPA.

[image]

As for what the various current ratings are for on the 240 it is difficult to know without more information. Different heaters for different sized units perhaps, or different heat settings if there are any.